# Octobercms partials not updating

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

```
{#
    {% partial 'catalog/section' %}

    {% partial 'discounts/section' %}

    {% partial 'other/how-to' %}

    {% partial 'other/contacts' %}
#}
```

I must update partials but if I update partials above it is not changing but If I remove {#  #} it is updating.

What may be problem?
What is the use of {# #}?

Comment: `{# --- #}` is used to comment code, so basically if you put them, your code will not execute which is in between them

Comment: thank you actually I am new to Octobercms

Comment: sure np, I would suggest going through its documentation. it will help you a lot.